# Blender Geometry Nodes: How to find vertex neighbor id's and positions

Tags: geometry-nodes

Given that Blender Geo Nodes "Vertex Neighbors" nodes only outputs only the neighboring vertex and face counts and NOT the point ID's and positions, how is it possible to get the neighboring vertices of a vertex and their positions? I'm trying to do a dot product calculation at each vertex in regard to its vertex neighbor position.

My aim is to determine the dot product of two edges that go from each vertex to their immediate neighbors so as to be able to calculate the winding angle, I'm trying to see if I can tell geo nodes the difference between concavity and convexity. My ultimate is to be able to duplicate a profile curve at each vertex so that they can form a complete lofted surface.

Comment: What are you using the dot-product for?

Comment: In any case, this is not easily solved with a simple node. The difficulty lies in the fact that each vertex can have an indefinite number of neighbors. So please be so kind and try to refine your question, add a picture and maybe share the node tree and/or the blend file. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not being so clear as to what I was trying to accomplish. My aim is to determine the dot product of two edges that go from each vertex to their immediate neighbors so as to be able to calculate the winding angle, I'm trying to see if I can tell geo nodes the difference between concavity and convexity. My ultimate is to be able to duplicate a profile curve at each vertex so that they can form a complete lofted surface.

Comment: fist of: you could use the *edges of vertex* node. second of: it doesn't matter because the *dot* won't give the the ***signed*** *angle* because you don't have an axis to set as up to differentiate it, and you can't use the normal because it gets recalculated according to the orientation. this is all only if there are no faces, but there are then the normal could work, however in that case you can use the edge angle node...