Geo Node Maggot Simulation: Problem! Maybe indices not consistent?
I'm coming up with a problem with a quiet complex system that is probably to complex for my level of geo nodes knowledge. Still i hope to solve and understand it, learning with challenges...
I'm building a creeping maggot system and it all works quiet good. In the posted .blend it's already heavily simplified as it also involves Curve Deform-Nodes, collision, much more synchronized set_positions etc.
The last thing i wanted to add to this simulation was the maggots to stop for some time and start creeping again (and waving their heads while they stop, that also works in the bigger file).
The problem occurs when i try to offset this 'stoptime' per maggot/index/island index. I've been trying to debug for few days, but just can't.
I see in the spreadsheet that there are strange things going on with the indices, they are flipping around... To me it seems like the island index assignment would loose consistency, maybe due to the 'top' or 'age' attribute in conjunction with the delete-node???? I have no clue...
I tried to simplify the system as much as possible to show the problem. In the file you find two objects, one is with working maggot system, but without 'stoptime'-offset, and one not working with offset.
Would be really really kind if someone could look into it and help me.
Thx!!!




I just simplified the scene even more:
You can see the indices flipping at the end of the spreadsheet after frame 120 (what is the time when the movement has to stop). I marked the frame red in the node tree that contains the offsetting operation that brakes the system.
You can just hit play, once with the 'maggots working'-object visible, once with the 'maggots not working'-object visible. The first one stops cleanly and continous the movement after some time, the second one starts stuttering.
New blend:



I guess it is necessary that i reduce the tree even more to the actual problem for easier examination. I'll do that later, sorry for bothering you with a too big node tree.

I attached an even more simplified .blend in my previous post, hopefully that helps.

it looks like you aren't adding any new islands in the simulation (you are only extendeding the old ones); is this true?

Yes, that's right, the number of mesh island stays the same.

Before the sim, there are 10 points generated that then gets extruded. The extruded vertex 'top' gets the attribute 'top' assigned. In the next sim cycle, the 'top' vertex gets extruded and so on. The attribute 'age' determines when the vertices at the other end get deleted.

This system i mostly copied from Erindale and other resources. Now there is also the 'time' attribute that counts the frames until the given value (i think here it is 310 frames), then the sim pauses for 90 frames.

This is realized by setting up the additional switch for the extrusion selection. But the old attributes should be passed further still (i hope!). At least it works with the islands stopping all at the same time. But once i introduce a time offset per island (by manipulating the framecount with the mesh island index) it gets strange. You can see it very obvious at the end of the spreadsheet when the 'maggots' stop. The indices starts 'jumping'.

if you aren't adding new islands, then just store them before the sim (because it's vertices it could be the index instead of using the islands index if you want).

Thank you for your advise, i will try it ones i'm back on my computer. I'm wandering how a captured/stored index attribute gets then processed in the sim, as the initial vertex will be deleted after a while. I thought it might be necessary to pass on such a consistent index per island from one vertex to the following/newly extruded every step, to guarantee consistency. Do you have an idea how to find connected vertex neighbours in a mesh line?

Ahh, i just found this post of yours: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274709/blender-geometry-nodes-how-to-find-vertex-neighbor-ids-and-positions Should be possible to set something up with 'edges of vertex' in conjunction with the edge vertices node, right? I never used these nodes before.

Rolando, you said > "I'm wandering how a captured/stored index attribute gets then processed in the sim, as the initial vertex will be deleted after a while. I thought it might be necessary to pass on such a consistent index per island from one vertex to the following/newly extruded every step, to guarantee consistency" this is unnecessary. the way it behaves is that is propagates / gets inherented by any geometry made from it either extruded, duplicated, or even instanced on it.

Thank you very much, shmuel! It was that easy, just storing the index before the sim. Sim still needs some refinement, but this problem seems to be solved. Should i post it as answer?

I think I'll copy paste the comment then. if you want any edit then edit it (if you don't have editing privileges then leave any images or edits in the comments.

if you aren't adding new islands duringthe sim, then just store them before the sim and because it's vertices you could even use the index instead of using the islands.
you don't value to worry about propagating the (attribute) ID yourself, because the way it behaves is that when you captures or store an attribute it propagates / gets inherented by any geometry made from it either extruded, duplicated, or even instanced on it.
(there are some cases, though, that will loos attributes when on certain types, or certain domains, and or when using certain operations (nodes), but generally it will propagate on it's own.)
